# Cambiar photo al escoger select

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria que al seleccionar elementos del desplegable, a parte de obtener el número en segundos, en un cuadro de información se mostrase cierto contenido.

Una de las cosas que quiero conseguir es que la imagen en el `div photo-info` se actualice según la selección.

Creo que no voy mal encaminado, pero cuando cambio la opción del desplegable la imagen no se muestra, y en la consola recibo un error de `undefined`. (las imagenes las tengo en local)

```js
// Añadiendo los tipos de tea

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectTea = document.getElementById('tea');


//Array
var teas = [
    {
        name: 'Earl Grey',
        time: 180
    },
    {
        name: 'Otro té',
        time: 300
    },
    {
        name: 'Último té',
        time: 240
    }];


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < teas.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = teas[i].name;

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = teas[i].time;

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectTea.appendChild(opt);

}

// Añadiendo las personas

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectPeople = document.getElementById('ho');


//Array
var people = [
    {
        name: 'George Orwell',
        time: -50,
        photo: 'img/orwell.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Kerome',
        time: 80,
        photo: 'img/kerome.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Churchill',
        time: 30,
        photo: 'img/churchill.jpg'
    }
  ];


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = people[i].name;

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = people[i].time;

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectPeople.appendChild(opt);

}

//Funcion sumar los tiempos, Number para convertir los string a numero y mostrar el resultado

function totalTime(p1, p2) {
    return p1 + p2;
}

function mostrar() {
    document.getElementById("resultadouu").innerHTML = totalTime(Number(selectTea.value), Number(selectPeople.value)) + " segundos";
}

//Mostrar imagen segun seleccion

function showphoto() {
    var img = document.querySelector(".photo-info img");
    img.src = this.photo;
}

document.querySelector("ho").onchange = showphoto;
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    
    
}

.tea {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.likeho {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.resultado {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.desplegables {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

select {
    font-size: 35px;
    border: solid black 5px; 
}


.photo-info img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

.info-panel {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 40px; 
    border: dotted black 2px;
}

.photo-info {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.info-text {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#resultadouu {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Teassistant</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">


        <div class="title">
            <h1>Teassistant</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="desplegables">
            <div class="tea">


                <select id="tea" name="tea">

            </select>

            </div>

            <div class="likeho">

                <select id="ho" name="ho">
  
            </select>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div>

            <h1 class="resultado">Resultado<br>


                <button onclick="mostrar()">Muestra el tiempo en segundos</button>

                <p id="resultadouu"></p>


            </h1>



        </div>

        <div class="info-panel">
            <div class="photo-info">


                <img src='img/churchill.jpg'>


            </div>

            <div class="info-text">

                <div class="britton-title">
                    <h1>George Orwell</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="britton-text">

                    Eric Arthur Blair, más conocido por el pseudónimo de George Orwell, fue un escritor y periodista británico, cuya obra lleva la marca de las experiencias personales vividas por el autor en tres etapas


                </div>


            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿En que linea te da el undefined?

Comment: Hola Lithorell. En la 100 del js

Comment: ¿Y a que corresponde la 100 de JS?. Date cuenta que aqui no aparecen las lineas.

Comment: Cierto. A esta funcion: document.querySelector("ho").onchange = showphoto;

Comment: por que no usas `selectPeople.onchange`  ya que la has creado ? Asi se soluciona el error

Comment: Tengo la intuicion de que cuando ejecutas esa linea aun no esta cargado el DOM y por lo tanto no encuentra el elemento "ho". Para solucionarlo vas a necesitar la funcion document.onload para que se ejecute despues de cargar el DOM

Comment: el problema al cambiar es que usas `img.src = this.photo;` donde `this` es un `<select>` y tu intentas que sea un `people` para poder coger el `src`

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Añadiendo los tipos de tea
//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectTea = document.getElementById('tea');
//Array
var teas = [
    {
        name: 'Earl Grey',
        time: 180
    },
    {
        name: 'Otro té',
        time: 300
    },
    {
        name: 'Último té',
        time: 240
    }];


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < teas.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = teas[i].name;

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = teas[i].time;

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectTea.appendChild(opt);

}

// Añadiendo las personas

//Escogiendo el elemento
var selectPeople = document.getElementById('ho');


//Array
var people = [
    {
        name: 'George Orwell',
        time: -50,
        photo: 'img/orwell.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Kerome',
        time: 80,
        photo: 'img/kerome.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Churchill',
        time: 30,
        photo: 'img/churchill.jpg'
    }
  ];


//Loop
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    // creando la nueva option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    // Añadiendo texto al elemento (opt)
    opt.innerHTML = people[i].name;

    //Añadiendo un valor al elemento (opt)
    opt.value = people[i].time;

    // Añadiendo opt al final del selector (sel)
    selectPeople.appendChild(opt);

}

//Funcion sumar los tiempos, Number para convertir los string a numero y mostrar el resultado

function totalTime(p1, p2) {
    return p1 + p2;
}

function mostrar() {
    document.getElementById("resultadouu").innerHTML = totalTime(Number(selectTea.value), Number(selectPeople.value)) + " segundos";
}

//Mostrar imagen segun seleccion

function showphoto() {
    var img = document.querySelector(".photo-info img");
    img.src = this.photo;
}

document.querySelector("ho").onchange = showphoto;
});
```